# Microsoft Access ADP view designer always adds _1 to tables and does not show the fields inside each table

Tags: sql, ms-access, adp

The view designer inside Microsoft Access ADP always adds _1 to all table names, also all table fields are not shown. The only thing that shows inside the table is *(All Columns)

I have tried access 2007 and access 2010 and both have the same output. 
Every view inside the database is shown in this way, and the fields never show.
This problem is within a specific database. Other database show normally.
I am forced to make my changes inside the SQL Sever.

I found something on the Microsoft website that says if the database server driver does not have permission then the fields will not populate, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if someone else has the same issue.

Turns out that the database name included the "." and space character, and this was the source of the problem even though everything else worked fine. Access was not finding the table fields. I renamed the database and the problem was solved.